# Is this function uniformly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am using the following definition of uniformly convex:

> A continuous functional $G:Y \to R$ is *uniformly convex* on a ball $$B(0,\delta):=\{y\in Y : \|y\| < \delta\}$$ if there exists a continuous functional $\phi_\delta : Y \to R_{+}$ such that $\phi_\delta(y) = 0$ iff $y$ is zero element of $Y$ and
>
> $$ G\left(\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right) + \phi_\delta(y_2-y_1) \leq \frac{1}{2} (G(y_1) + G(y_2)) \quad \forall y_1,y_2 \in B(0,\delta).$$

I want to know in which region the following functional is uniformly convex with respect to $u$

$$G(x,u(x)) = \frac{1}{2}\int | -I_L(x) + I_R(x) + \gamma (x,u(x)) u(x)|^2 dx $$

where $\gamma(x,u(x))$ is the average integral between [0,1] of

$$\partial_x I_R(x+s u(x)) ds$$

I defined the sets

$$S^+ = \{ x\in \Omega : \gamma(x,u(x)) \geq \alpha \text{ and } I_R(x) > I_L (x)$$

$$S^- = \{ x\in \Omega : \gamma(x,u(x)) \geq -\alpha \text{ and } I_L(x) > I_R (x).$$
With the definition of these two sets I can ensure that in $S = S^+ \cup S^-$ I have the following lower bound for $G$:

$$\int |-I_L + I_R + \alpha u|^2 \leq G[u]$$

Since I found a quadratic lower bound and there is therefore a quadratic gap between this lower bound and my functional $G[u]$ I should be able to prove that $G$ is uniformly convex but I cannot manage. Any answer would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you in Sant Cugat?

Comment: No... I am in Germany but I worked in Sant Cugat for one year. Why?

Comment: Oh, I am living here for a while. Although I'm leaving on monday either way :)